# cannot start python newly made exe

Tags: python, executable

I've written a GUI "app" with Python Tkinter and everything is working great. Then I used pyinstaller to make an EXE file out of it - again success. But when i try to run my app on another PC, nothing happens. No error, nothing. I've tried building a single EXE file using the --onefile option; I've tried not putting it all in one file --> on my machine it's working, on the otherS - not. I even copied the msvcr90.dll file and put it in the same directory as the executable - no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Try importing traceback and sys, wrapping the entire program in a try/except block, and in the except clause, write this line to a file: `"".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))`. You may be getting an exception that closes the console so quickly you don't see it. This should capture the exception and write it to a file so you can examine it.

Comment: After doing this, edit your question to include the outcome: the full traceback (if you get one) and whether or not a file was created.

Comment: Everything is solved, I used a different freezer (CX_freezer) and it works great.